# How to find referer of redirect to oauth client's callback

Tags: laravel

I am having trouble setting up a generic oauth client (and can't find good material on google).

I have this as my route to receive the callback from the oauth process:

```
Route::get('/oauth/callback', function (Request $request) {
    $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

    $response = $http->post('https://www.wunderlist.com/oauth/access_token', [
        'client_id'     => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'client_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'code'          => $request->code
    ]);
});
```

but in order to make it generic, I must be able to identify where the redirect came from.
something in the lines of

```
$service = App\Service::where(<field>, $request-><information about the referer>);
```

*does Request contain any kind of information that can help me identify the source of the redirect?* I looked at the object with `dd()` and couldn't find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work around the problem by defining the callback url so that it contains a query parameter identifying the service.

This means that I tell the service to callback to `/oauth/callback?service=XXX`
and I find it in my services table like this:

```
$service = Service::where('slug', Input::get('service'))->firstOrFail();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `request()->headers->get('referer')` to check the referrer url.

Comment: I should have mentioned that. Sorry.
The referer header has the address of my own page:

```
"referer" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "http://localhost:8000/home"
      ]
```

as my page redirects to the service, which redirects to my callback